# VB.NET and WPF SplashScreen with System.Threading.Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, multithreading

The following code is C# and Windows Forms and it is okey.

The following code is taken from this YouTube video: *[C# Tutorial - Splash Screen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZ4BkPyZllY)*

```
namespace SplashScreen
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartForm));
            t.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            InitializeComponent();
            t.Abort();
        }

        public void StartForm()
        {
            Application.Run(new frmSplashScreen());
        }
    }
}
```

The following code is VB.NET and Windows Forms, and it is okey.

```
Class MainWindow

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) _
      Handles Button1.Click

        Dim t As System.Threading.Thread = _
          New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf StartForm)
        t.Start()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        t.Abort()
    End Sub

    Public Sub StartForm()
        Application.Run(New frmSplashScreen)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I want to convert the above code to a VB.NET and WPF application.

The following code needs to be repaired.

```
Class MainWindow

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) _
      Handles Button1.Click

        Dim t As System.Threading.Thread = _
          New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf StartForm)
        t.Start()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        t.Abort()
    End Sub

    Public Sub StartForm()
        Dim mySplashScreenWindow As New SplashScreenWindow()
        mySplashScreenWindow.Owner = Me
        mySplashScreenWindow.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the error message:

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require
>   this.

Here is the error screen shot: https://prnt.sc/kumom7

Answer (score 2):

You should invoke your `StartForm` code using a [`dispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Threading_Dispatcher_Invoke_System_Windows_Threading_DispatcherPriority_System_Delegate_).

So your `StartForm` should look like this:

```
Public Sub StartForm()
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub()
        Dim mySplashScreenWindow As New SplashScreenWindow()
        mySplashScreenWindow.Owner = Me
        mySplashScreenWindow.ShowDialog()
    End Sub)
End Sub
```

You should read [Understanding and Using COM Threading Models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx) for a better understanding of threads and STA.

Comment: @DannyColeiro: please do not ask people to delete answers. You can vote on how helpful you think a post is if you disagree with their solution, but Paul does not have to delete anything. If you changed your question so much as to invalidate answers, then *you should have asked a new question instead*. It's not the responsibility of answerers to follow question changes to that extend, and questions should not fundamentally change when answered.